# Adobe cross-country licensing and online purchases

Tags: untagged

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can you help me with my software licensing issue?](https://serverfault.com/questions/215405/can-you-help-me-with-my-software-licensing-issue)

I am running a small company and I want to buy cheaper software online, but I don't know if it is Legal and Valid the license in my country. Where can I find answers?

Comment: I own my own business too, and know that software licenses can be a hefty expense. However, I emplore you to not cut corners and make sure you buy true software. You will profit more in the long run in both time and money.

Answer (score 2):

[Adobe publishes their licenses](http://www.adobe.com/products/eulas/), which will cover everything but your local laws. Thier licenses are extremely extensive and cover basically every situation (though they do not cover situations where your local laws apply). If your country's law prohibit purchasing foreign software this will be an issue, and not mentioned in Adobe's licenses. If you are unsure, consult a reseller or a local lawyer.